# How do I change the git branch from which I branched?

Tags: git, version-control, github, branching-and-merging

I was working on a feature branch and I did a `git checkout -b feature/other-feature`, did some work, committed it and then pushed it to origin feature/other-feature on github.

When I created a pull request from the other-feature branch on github I realised that it showed a load of commits from the original feature branch - commits that should rightfully be merged to develop from the original branch.

I think what I did wrong was to omit `git checkout develop` before I did `git checkout -b feature/other-feature` and so what I think I want to do to correct this situation is rebase other-feature onto develop.

But given that I've pushed my mistake to origin and other people have clones of this repo, do I need to rebase or do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to rebase your copy of `feature/other-feature`. However, in this case a simple `git rebase develop` will probably not work, because you branched off another feature branch, instead of directly off `develop`. You need to use `rebase --onto`:

```
git rebase --onto develop feature/earlier-feature feature/other-feature
```

Here, `feature/earlier-feature` is the feature branch you had checked out when you die the original 
`git checkout -b feature/other-feature`.

This rebase will:

1. Take the commits in `feature/other-feature` which are *not* in `feature/earlier-feature`.
2. Re-apply these commits to `develop`.

You should end up with a changed branch `feature/other-feature` which is now based on `develop`.

---

**Notes**

- Because of the rebasing you will have to force-push your branch to your GitHub repository. This is not a problem, *as long as you have the only clone of your repository*. If you use the repo with others, things are more difficult (see below).
- The rebase may cause conflicts. You will have to resolve these manually.
- Further reading: The concepts behind rebasing, and the meaning of `rebase --onto` are well explained in the book "Pro Git". See chapter 3.6, [Git Branching - Rebasing](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

---

**If others have cloned your repository**

You write

> But given that I've pushed my mistake to origin and other people have
>   clones of this repo, do I need to rebase or do something else?

You can still rebase as described above. However, you must not force-push the rebased branch under the old name. Instead, create a copy of the branch:

```
git checkout -b feature/other-feature-2 feature/other-feature
```

This will create a new branch `feature/other-feature-2` that is an exact copy of `feature/other-feature`. You can then rebase the new branch, and push it under the new name.
Then tell everyone that `feature/other-feature` has been superseded by `feature/other-feature-2`, and delete `feature/other-feature` on GitHub. Having to tell everyone is the price you pay for rebasing :-).

Comment: thank you @sleske. I've clarified the question because other people have cloned this repo. in what way does this make it more difficult?

Comment: @jah: I have added some more info to my answer. Hope it helps.